# IOS firebase stacktrace are not symbolicated

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting, symbolicate

I have integrated the forebase crash report as per googles documentation and its working as expected except, the stack trace is not symbolicated.

In the firebase console, I see the following message

Future stack traces for UUID ******** will be symbolicated using the uploaded symbol file.

But stack trace are not symbolicated and I get messages like

1033138 + 418738 instead of method name.

Comment: The message is saying that *future* traces will be symbolicated.  You're probably looking at a crash that was sent before you uploaded symbol files.  Have you tried generating a crash after the upload?

Comment: yes,problem is no crash was symbolicating.

Found the solution,i needed to give 777 permisison to the foler PODS/FirebaseCrash recursively and after that it worked like a charm.